# How to detect if form-building function is called for the first time?

Tags: forms

In my form building function I need to render some things basing on user's actions. But if the form building function is called for the very first time I want to put a form deliberately in slightly inconsistent state (I have my reasons, long story).

How can I reliably detect if the form building function was called for the first time, or if the form was already presented to the user and now it's built due to AJAX call or to allow user to fix input errors?

Currently I'm using `empty($form_state['input'])` but I have this feeling there is a better, more reliable way and I forgot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add our own value to $form_state in a hook_form_alter().  If it doesn't already exist (eg., `!isset($form_state['my_var'])`), then you know it is the first build.

Comment: Yes, i guess node form also does something in similar way check this link https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7

Comment: +1 from me. If the Form API does not have any built-in mechanism, will do it that way. Let's see if anyone knows a better way. Will accept this, if there appears to be none.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Drupal 9, your form_alter function() will run at least twice without the value you add to form_state being defined. Now that it is an object and not an array, the only mechanism I know of to set an arbitrary value is get() and set(), and the values live in the storage property of form_state. According to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/158746):

> form_state['storage'] is ought to be changed in submit handler not in builder.

That comment is 15 years old, so maybe it isn't so definitive nowadays. When I try it, I find that my values need to be initialized at least twice.

The only reliable indication I have found for "the beginning of this form process" (ie if you are editing a node, and you reload the URL, that starts a new form process, even though it's the same entity) is that both form_state values and input are empty. I hope to eventually find something better.